# Storing subcollections in Cloud Firestore

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to develop a simple e-commerce using Flask and Cloud Firebase as my data storage.

I read that I can have collections within a document. My `carts` collection looks like this: `book_list` is a nested dictionary of carted books.

[image]

Now instead of using a nested dictionary, I plan to use subcollection containing the carted books in a cart.

So when I have a new cart, I will have a document for the cart, and a subcollection inside that cart document. Now the hope is for something like this.

[image]

How do I go about storing a new document for the cart and then the subcollection? Should I store the cart document first and then set the subcollection of books for that cart?

I have this code in Python:

```
  cart_ref = db.collection('carts').document(user_id)
  cart_ref.set(cart)
  cart_book_ref = cart_ref.collection('books').document(book_id)
  cart_book_ref.set(sub_cart)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do

```
cart_ref = db.collection('carts').document(user_id).collection('books').document(book_id).set(cart);
```

You can still store in sub collections even if the above collections don't exist anymore/yet.